# Error while running programe?

Tags: android, android-layout

there is an error while i am running my application? can anybody tell me why this error appeared and how to resolve it.

ERROR IS :[2011-02-23 17:46:48 - diffrentviews] W/ResourceType( 4072): Bad XML block: header size 166 or total size 0 is larger than data size 0
[2011-02-23 17:46:48 - diffrentviews] C:\Documents and Settings\a.singh\workspace\diffrentviews\res\menu\main_menu.xml:7: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'alphabeticShortcuts' in package 'android'

Comment: Can you paste the content of `main_menu.xml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `android:alphabeticShortcut` ,not  `android:alphabeticShortcuts` ..

There is an extra `s`.